# enabled property of useQuery only works the first time - React-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using react-query and I am trying to understand why my query is running even if the enabled property is false.

The flow is the following:

1. I enter the page. The property is a variable that is false. It does not run the query. CORRECT.
2. I make a change through a button, the property is true. It runs the query and then it turns the variable back to false. CORRECT.
3. I make any changes to the page, the query runs agains even though the variable is false. INCORRECT.

Is this the correct behaviour of react-query?

This is my code:

*QUERY*

```
  const {
    data: searchResultsQuery,
    isError: searchResultsErrorQuery,
    isLoading: searchResultsLoading
  } = useQuery(
    [
      "search: " +
        search +
        "-generator:" +
        generatorSearch +
        "-category:" +
        categorySearch,
      search,
      generatorSearch,
      categorySearch
    ],
    () => {
      return searchPrompts(categorySearch, generatorSearch, search);
    },
    {
      ...reactQueryParams,
      enabled: triggerSearch
    }
  );
```

*UseEffect that runs when loading the query, and sets the variable to false*

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchResultsLoading) {
      console.log("false");
      setTriggerSearch(false);
    }
  }, [searchResultsLoading]);
```

The variable is changed from a button on click and its a simple SetState Function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has to set "keepPreviousData" to true, otherwise the query key was changing and returning undefined.